# Is there a way to enable/disable subsets of data taken by a formula?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

There are 2 sheets: `Data` and `Stats`. `Data` contains records (several hundred) that are divided into ~20 categories. On the `Stats` sheet, I want to do various calculations. Is there a way to compose formulas in a way to take in only the categories that are enabled?

Previously, this was implemented in Excel, where `SUMIFS` function makes it possible (the conditions are inclusive). But in GS `SUMIFS` does not evaluate further conditions if condition1 is true. Or: I'm doing something wrong. Totally possible.

`=SUMIF(Data!K:K, "<="&G3, Data!N:N)` This version is a single condition. It says 'give me the sum of N column on Data sheet, provided corresponding value of K is less than or equal to G3'.

`SUMIFS(Data!N:N, Data!K:K, "<="&G3, Data!B:B, G2:G20)` (the syntax is slightly different in comparison with `SUMIF`)

Here, range `G2:G20` contains the list of categories that I want to be able to switch on and off, and `B` column contains category labels. In Excel, when you indicate a range like this, it works. In GS - not so much.

Regardless of the Excel implementation, what would be the best way to achieve this *on/off functionality* in Google Sheets?

Comment: can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(Data!N:N, Data!K:K<=G3, 
 REGEXMATCH(""&Data!:B:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, G2:G20))))
```

note that G3 is overlapping with G2:G20 so something is not right in your referencing tho

Comment: thanks! You're right about the referencing, it should be `F3` not `G3`